# Using objc_msgSendSuper_stret will raise `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)`

Tags: objective-c

I'm using `objc_msgSendSuper` and `objc_msgSendSuper_stret` to invoke the superclass's implementation of its superclass.

The `objc_msgSendSuper` works well as following:

```
struct objc_super supersSuper;
supersSuper.receiver = self;
supersSuper.super_class = object_getClass(class_getSuperclass(class_getSuperclass(self)));  

return objc_msgSendSuper(&supersSuper, _cmd);
```

But using `objc_msgSendSuper_stret` will raise a runtime error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)`:

```
// In Tier3 class
+ (CGPoint) point{
    struct objc_super supersSuper;
    supersSuper.receiver = self;
    supersSuper.super_class = object_getClass(class_getSuperclass(class_getSuperclass(self)));  

    // raise EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT) when invoking objc_msgSendSuper_stret
    return ((CGPoint(*)(struct objc_super *, SEL))objc_msgSendSuper_stret)(&supersSuper, _cmd); 
}
```

The selector did exist in the target class:

```
[Tier1 point]; // return {10, 10}
```

I see lots of `objc_msgSend`, `objc_msgSendSuper` and `objc_msgSend_stret` examples, but it's rarely to find an example using `objc_msgSendSuper_stret`.

---

**Update**

I found the old API of `objc_msgSend_stret` is the following:

```
void objc_msgSend_stret(void * stretAddr, id theReceiver, SEL theSelector,  ...)
```

but current API is:

```
void objc_msgSend_stret(id self, SEL op, ...)
```

I think Apple did change the function signature of `objc_msgSend_stret`. Doesn't it?

---

**Update-2**

I did try the following:

```
CGPoint retVal = CGPointMake(0, 0);
// Cast to old API signature.
((void(*)(CGPoint *, id, SEL))objc_msgSend_stret)(&retVal, self, @selector(point));

return retVal;
```

This casting will make the function `objc_msgSend_stret` call succeed. The target method did been invoked, and the target method returns {10, 10}. But the return value which we got is not correct, it was still {0, 0}.

BTW, I find the code can't work under 32-bit architecture (still raise `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)`). It only works under 64-bit architecture.

---

**Update-3**

Class declaration:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject
+ (CGRect)rect;
+ (CGPoint)point;
@end
@implementation TestClass
+ (CGRect)rect;{
    NSLog(@"+[TestClass rect] is invoked");
    return CGRectMake(3, 3, 3, 3);
}
+ (CGPoint)point;{
    NSLog(@"+[TestClass point] is invoked");
    return CGPointMake(10, 10);
}

+ (CGRect)rectRuntimeTest;{
    CGRect retVal = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    ((void(*)(CGRect *, id, SEL))objc_msgSend_stret)(&retVal, self, @selector(rect));
    return retVal;
}

+ (CGPoint)pointRuntimeTest{
    CGPoint retVal = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    ((void(*)(CGPoint *, id, SEL))objc_msgSend_stret)(&retVal, self, @selector(point));
    return retVal;
}
@end
```

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, test the following:

```
CGRect retRect = [TestClass rectRuntimeTest];
NSLog(@"retVal: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(retRect));

CGPoint retPoint = [TestClass pointRuntimeTest];
NSLog(@"retPoint: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(retPoint));
```

The output (under 64-bit architecture iOS Simulator):

```
> +[TestClass rect] is invoked
> retVal: {{3, 3}, {3, 3}}
> +[TestClass point] is invoked
> retPoint: {0, 0}  // Should be {10, 10} which is returned from +[TestClass point]
```

The output (under 32-bit architecture iOS Simulator):

```
`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbfffca78)`
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/166226-objc-msgsend-stret-intel-crashes.html) question, it appears that `CGPoint` is a "simple" return value, and so you should use `objc_msgSendSuper` in this case. When returning CGRect, you apparently should use `objc_msgSendSuper_stret`.

Regarding the strange signature of the _stret variants, don't let the private signatures bother you, relying on the public signatures is correct. This is showcased in detail [here](http://blog.lazerwalker.com/blog/2013/10/12/the-objective-c-runtime-and-objc-msgsend-stret).

Other than that, you should always cast objc_msg*Send* to the non-variadic (i.e., with all arguments well-defined) form, and call that (you do it in some places, but you should in all places).

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I did some research and the so called "simple" return value is "simple" when the structure is returned in the register or not.

The POD (Plain Old Data) structs will be returned through registers if they fit some standard criteria according to these ABIs:

- IA-21 ABI (a.k.a x86, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/130-IA-32_Function_Calling_Conventions/IA32.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002492-SW5) - structs of size 1 or 2 bytes are returned in eax, 4 or 8 bytes are returned in eax and edx.
- AMD64 ABI (a.k.a. x86_64, https://people.freebsd.org/~obrien/amd64-elf-abi.pdf#14, section 3.2.3) - if a struct fits into two 8-bytes then it's returned through registers rax and rdx.
- ARM Procedure Call Standard (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf, section 5.4) -  up to 4 bytes are returned through r0.
- ARM64 Procedure Call Standard (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0055b/IHI0055B_aapcs64.pdf, section 5.5) - it looks like the same rules apply for returning value as passing arguments - that means that composite types up to 8 registers (8 * 8 = 64 bytes max) are passed back into registers r0-r8.

So to sum everything up we have to use `objc_msgSend_stret` function when:

- x86 and `sizeof(struct) == 1 | 2 | 4 | 8`
- x86_64 and `sizeof(struct) > 16`
- armv7 and `sizeof(struct) > 4`
- arm64 and `sizeof(struct) > 64`

Else just use `objc_msgSend`

I'm not 100% sure about arm64, because the standard is wayyy too abstract :)

Comment: There's no stret for arm64.